# Parsing log file with sed in linux

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed, cygwin

I'm trying to use `sed` for parsing log file to extract xml messages from it using the template. I want to get all xml messages in new file.

I'm using this command `sed 's/<sending>\(.*\)<\/sending>/\1/' input.out>output.xml`

input.out have following сontent:

```
 WARNING: Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: byte[], Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><sending><query>        <describe>            <data>city</data>        </describe>    </query></sending>]
Sep 26, 2016 11:54:30 AM org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger log
WARNING: Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: byte[], Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><sending>    <query>        <key_info/>    </query></sending>]
```

I'm expecting to get result like this:

```
 <query>        <describe>            <data>city</data>        </describe>    </query>    <query>        <key_info/>    </query>
```

But i only get source file without `<sending>` and `</sending>` elements like this:

```
WARNING: Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: byte[], Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><query>        <describe>            <data>city</data>        </describe>    </query>]
Sep 26, 2016 11:54:30 AM org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger log
WARNING: Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: byte[], Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>    <query>        <key_info/>    </query>]
```

Sorry for my english and have a nice day. Thank you for help.

Comment: try `grep -oP '\<sending\>\K.*(?=\<\/sending\>)' filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*<sending>\(.*\)<\/sending>.*/\1/' input.out>output.xml
```

you forget to *remove* surrounding part of the line (`.*`), sed only take the content of your pattern and you don't include char before or after your *sending* bloc

now i suggest

```
sed -e '/.*<sending>\(.*\)<\/sending>.*/!d' -e 's//\1/' input.out>output.xml
```

it remove line that don't have the sending bloc. Don't forget that sed take the longest partterne available so if there are 2 bloc on same line (or more) it take from first sending until last /sending

Comment: NeronLeVelu, thank you a lot, i make out the problem